# iOS - GameKit get list of matches in progress?

Tags: ios, game-center

How can I get a list of games (matches). Are the list of matches stored on GameCenter servers, or am I suppose to store them on the device?

Documentation doesn't seem to have any information about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking at GKMatch documentation instead of GKTurnBasedMatch. I think GKMatch deals with live games only, and that's why it doesn't need to store any of the match data.

The following method in GKTurnBasedMatch returns the list of matches:

```
+ (void)loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *matches, NSError
*error))completionHandle
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this method: the array of `GKTurnBasedMatch` objects returned MAY OR MAY NOT have the `matchData` property instantiated.

Comment: and for that GKTurnBasedMatch has a nice method: -(void)loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *matchData, NSError *error))completionHandler